# ASP.NET CORE MVC identity users and roles doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a ASP.NET CORE MVC 3.1 application with Identity enabled:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

The DB Context inherits from identity:

```
ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
```

Startup configuration:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
  name: "default",
  pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

However, it doesn't enforce authentication when navigating through the application. If however, I use services.AddDefaultIdentity, it works but I lose functionality of accessing RolManager for getting the roles of authenticated user.

Can you please advise on what do I need to do to enforce the authentication?

Comment: Did you mark your controller / pages with the `AuthorizeAttribute` ?

Comment: @Marco: I did not. I expect authentication to occur before authorization takes place, isn't the case ? There should be a session cookie there before the application enforces authorization. With default identity, controllers were not marked with authorize attribute but authentication was still enforced.

Comment: @Marco: Is it then ok to use this way of working, more specifically, to decorate the controllers with authorize ? I don't have any specific requirements, it's just that I want the authentication/authorization to work properly.

Comment: I'll give you 2 possibilities. Let me write up an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities:

1. Decorate each endpoint you want to have protected with `[Authorize]`. This can get very repetetive in larger codebases.
2. Globally require Authorization on your endpoints:

```cs
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
         //or | and  MapControllersWithViews()
         endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
         endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();
     });
```

Be aware, that this will also protect your Login endpoints as well, so you have to exclude them, by decorating them with `[AllowAnonymous]`.

Details:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rau